# How to migrate AWS MySQL server rds to Azure MySQL server

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

How to migrate, copy MySQL data to Azure MySQL server? I have aws rds MySQL server and I want to transfer the data to Azure.

I see that Azure has MySQL server configuration via the portal but  can't find any source address of MySQL server to copy from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the Azure Data Migration Service: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/